# express js encode headers to utf-8

Tags: node.js, express, encoding, utf-8, header

I am using express js 4.13.3 and nodejs 12 
I am getting request with header `name: "John D�m"` I don't know even the encoding it has, so I don't know how to convert it.
the result should be `name: "John Döm"`

this is the routing

```
var express = require('express')

var app = express();

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.get('/drivers', function(req,res){
res.send(req.headers["name"])
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Up: http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

I tried `res.header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");`

can I set express to encode? with middleware or something?
thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you post more about driver.js ?

Comment: @malix changed it so now it has the function, but the function is not the problem. the problem is the encoding

Comment: what do you see if you do `console.log(req.headers("name"))` ?

Comment: @Daffa see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this worked for me:

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(req.headers.name, null, 2), 'utf-8');
```

but not this:

```
res.send(req.headers.name)
```

So I ended up with:

```
    var string = req.headers.name;
    return res.send('<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>' +
        string +
    '</body></html>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve problem with bad incoming request headers encoding. They are expect to be encoded in iso-8859-1, but my OIDC provider uses UTF-8. No way to change. Finally used this:

```
name = Buffer.from(req.headers['oidc_claim_name'], 'latin1').toString('utf-8');
```